# How large is planet Dagobah really?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

When Luke went to look for Yoda on the planet Dagobah, he

> landed/crashed quite close to Yoda's home.

This implies Dagobah is a rather small planet. I mean, if it was as big as the Earth or Mars, I guess it would be rather unlikely to

> find Yoda that quickly. Luke would have to fly above the planet's surface until he either senses a force-sensitive entity (that might be a first test of how good Luke is in using the force) or Yoda made himself recognizable somehow.

I'd say Dagobah can't be much bigger than Pluto. And given the fact that it has an Earth-like surface gravity it seems to be very dense too. Dagobah's atmosphere doesn't seem to be very high either and it's fully cloudy/foggy which again implies a small and dense planet.

Wookieepedia claims the planet is 14,410 kilometers (8,954 miles) in diameter but that seems unlikely.

> How would Luke find Yoda otherwise that quickly on an entire planet bigger than Earth?

Comment: You're forgetting about the Force.

Comment: I don't see how it "only" being as big as Pluto would make a difference. Pluto has a surface area of 16.7 million square km, according to Google; you're still hardly likely to land just next to someone in that amount of space. As others have said, we can assume it's the Force that guided him.

Comment: There are obviously many possible answers.

Comment: @Better not tell    Arrgh!  The question was closed when I was about to answer.  Anyway Luke's Force sense, or Yoda using the Force to attracrt Luke, or the will of the Force itself, "forced" Luke to land near Yoda.  And there is a minimum size for a planet that is habitable.  See my answer to: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41590/can-a-habitable-planet-be-smaller-than-0-58-earth-radii/41599#41599

Comment: @DanielRoseman Indeed, Pluto has 1/6 the diameter of Dagobah, and 1/36 the surface area. This is basically the difference between winning the lottery, and winning the lottery *and* rolling a 12 with a pair of dice - the dice part isn't really doing much.

Comment: There is no need to downvote just because it's a duplicate. I put the questions together myself by stating the other question does answer this one (or rather proposes possible answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of Universe

Star Wars uses its planetary locations as mere settings - hence why most of their planets can be described by a single biome.  It's a plot contrivance at best.

In Universe

The force was guiding Luke without him knowing it.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SingleBiomePlanet is the ecological equivalent to https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlanetOfHats